# how to insert and display true and false icon in apex?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, apex

i have a form and report pages, i want to insert a true mark and a false mark in some items
i am using oracle sql and plsql
how can i do that?
the output must be like in the picture[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a classic report and an interactive report, you can use "Column Formatting > HTML Expression" and then format the column according to your needs. The easiest is to use the success/danger color class [provided by APEX](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/ut/color-and-status-modifiers) for your theme. APEX also has its own font set based on "font awesome" called "[font APEX](https://apex.oracle.com/fontapex/)". Both can be seamlessly integrated in your report.

For this example I used the sample EMP/DEPT tables.

###### Classic Report AND Interactive Report

- Source Query:

```
select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       JOB,
       CASE WHEN job = 'PRESIDENT' THEN 'fa-check' ELSE 'fa-remove' END as icon_class,
       CASE WHEN job = 'PRESIDENT' THEN 'u-success-text' ELSE 'u-danger-text' END as color_class
  from EMP
 where  job in ('MANAGER','PRESIDENT')
```

- Set columns color_class and color_icon to hidden
- set BOSS column html expression to
  `<span aria-hidden="true" class="fa #ICON_CLASS# #COLOR_CLASS#"></span>`

###### Interactive Grid

- Source Query:

```
select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       JOB,
       CASE WHEN job = 'PRESIDENT' THEN 'fa-check' ELSE 'fa-remove' END as icon_class,
       CASE WHEN job = 'PRESIDENT' THEN 'u-success-text' ELSE 'u-danger-text' END as color_class
  from EMP
 where  job in ('MANAGER','PRESIDENT')
```

- Set columns color_class and color_icon to hidden
- IG does not support HTML Expression like the other reports, but similar layout can be achieved using "Column > Advanced > Column Initialization JavaScript Function".

```
function(config) {
    config.defaultGridColumnOptions = {
        cellTemplate: '<span aria-hidden="true" class="fa &ICON_CLASS. &COLOR_CLASS."></span>'
    };
    return config;
}
```

Note that the syntax is the &COLUMN_NAME. notation in the IG.

- Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what about interactive gride?

Comment: Updated my answer.  Next time, pls consider *providing details* in your question, saves me from going through all the possible cases ;).

Answer (score 2):

That looks like an interactive report.

One option is to **upload** image into Workspace files (that's located in Shared components) and then reference it in report's query as e.g.

```
select id,
  case when status = 1 then '<img src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#CB_CHECKED.JPG">' 
       else                 '<img src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#CB_NOT_CHECKED.JPG">' 
  end as status_image
from your_table
where ...
```

Don't forget to update `status_image` column's properties and turn "Escape special characters" OFF.

Result then looks like this:

[image]

(Of course, you'd upload your own images; that's the one I have).